# maintain selection in listview in two pane mode

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to create a gmail like interface where the user clicks on a list on the left and displays something on the right. I've gotten to the point where I have a list on the left and the user can click and the item gets highlighted (i'm a beginner). The problem is that if the user clicks on the for-now empty right side the highlighted item becomes no longer highlighted.

```
public class profileListFragment extends ListFragment {

    String[] countries = new String[] {"USA", "China"};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
//      View listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list));
        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_load_profile_list_layout,container, false);
        ListView lv = (ListView) retView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_orange_light);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
//      lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        return retView;
//      return super.onCreateView(inflater, container,  savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){

    }
}
```

If you need to see more code let me know. thanks in advance

#### EDIT

I've edited the code to be as follows:

```
lv.setSelector(R.drawable.profile_list_selector);
```

and the profile_list_selector.xml lives in the "drawable" folder and is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />


</selector>
```

What I notice now is that on the right screen the highlight is lost only when I click on a textbox on the right... If i click on a checkbox the highlighted item is maintained. Completely confused about all of this

Answer (score 1):

This questions is old, but I ran into this problem recently. I had a two-pane tablet layout. One pane had a ListView of items, the second pane displayed the items selected in the first pane. When an item in the ListView is selected I wanted to mark it so, and change the second pane. When the user rotated the device, I wanted to keep the current selection marked. Here is my solution:

In my list fragment, I keep a position. This is saved onSavedInstanceState and restore in onCreate. The position is updated during clicks and is also passed to the adapter. In the onListItemClick I also change the background color of the view accordingly.

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String LIST_ITEM_SELECTED = "list_item_selected";

    // keep the item selected to handle rotation
    private int mPositionSelected = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mPositionSelected = savedInstanceState.getInt(LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, 0);
        }

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity());
        mAdapter.setPositionSelected(mPositionSelected);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (Utils.isTablet(getActivity())) {
            outState.putInt(LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, mPositionSelected);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // If this is a tablet layout the inspections list is visible.
        // so send an event to change them.
        if (Utils.isTablet(getActivity())) {
            // set the old view's bg back to black
            l.getChildAt(mPositionSelected).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            // set the selected view's bg
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            // keep the selected position
            mPositionSelected = position;
            // tell the adapter the currently selected position
            mInspectionsByMonthAdapter.setPositionSelected(mPositionSelected);
            // let the other fragment know the items it should display
            EventBus.getInstance().post(...);
        } else {
            // else, we need to navigate to a new fragment.
        }
    }

}
```

In the adapter, I also keep the position selected. When the device is rotated, in the getView method, the selected item will be highlighted.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mPositionSelected;
    private Context mContext;

    static class MyViewHolder {
        TextView yearMonth;
        TextView number;
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setPositionSelected(int positionSelected) {
        mPositionSelected = positionSelected;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
            myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();

            myViewHolder.yearMonth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yearMonthInspections);
            myViewHolder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberOfInspections);

            convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);

        } else {
            myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        myViewHolder.yearMonth.setText(...);
        myViewHolder.number.setText(...);

        // set background color to the selected position.
        // this is used rotations. The position is maintained here and
        // in the fragment
        if (mPositionSelected == position) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no simple answer AFAIK.

You have to do something like a custom adapter which draws the currently selected item differently.  You also need to track the selected item state.

See this blog post for a possible solution.

http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2009/12/android-selected-state-listview-example/

Comment: It doesn't get deselected, it just doesn't draw as highlighted and I'm not aware of something simple like keepSelectedHighlightOnFocusChange or similar.  The only way I know is to do the drawing yourself in a custom adapter - which is the point of the example I've shown.  I'll see if I can dig up something a little more specific.  Back soon..

Comment: you're awsome thanks a lot... I spoke to a friend and he mentioned selectors... what do you think? That's what I'm researching now..